# Generics without parameterless constructors

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Can someone explain why in the code below, class1List does *not* require class1 to have a parameterless constructor, but class2list *does* require class 2 to have a parameterless constructor.

```
unit Unit11;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  class1 = class
  public
    constructor Create( const i : integer ); virtual;
  end;

  class1List<T : class1 > = class( TObjectList< T > )
  public
    function AddChild( const i : integer ) : T;
  end;

  class2 = class
  public
    constructor Create( const i : integer );
  end;

  class2List<T : class2 > = class( TObjectList< T > )
  public
    function AddChild( const i : integer ) : T;
  end;


implementation

{ class1List<T> }

function class1List<T>.AddChild(const i: integer): T;
begin
  Result := T.Create( i );
  inherited Add( Result );
end;

{ class2List<T> }

function class2List<T>.AddChild(const i: integer): T;
begin
  Result := T.Create( i );
  inherited Add( Result );
end;

{ class1 }

constructor class1.Create(const i: integer);
begin

end;

{ class2 }

constructor class2.Create(const i: integer);
begin

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function class1List<T>.AddChild(const i: integer): T;
begin
  Result := T.Create( i );
  inherited Add( Result );
end;
```

The constructor of `class1` is declared `virtual`. Therefore the compiler knows that `T.Create` yields an instance of `T` whose intended constructor has been called. Hence the compiler accepts this code. Note that earlier versions of the compiler would reject this code and force you to use the following cast

```
Result := T(class1(T).Create( i ));
```

But more recent versions of the compiler have removed the need for such trickery.

---

```
function class2List<T>.AddChild(const i: integer): T;
begin
  Result := T.Create( i );
  inherited Add( Result );
end;
```

The constructor of `class2` is not `virtual` and so the compiler knows that were it to call the constructor of `class2`, likely the class would not be properly initialised. It is prepared to call a parameterless constructor from the specialised type `T` if one exists, and you apply the `constructor` constraint when you declare the generic type. However, the language offers no way to apply a constructor constraint for constructors that accept parameters.

Now, you could apply the `constructor` constraint, but that would do no good. In order for the instance to be initialised properly, you need to call the constructor with the parameter. Which means, in practical terms, that you should use the first approach using a virtual constructor.

Don't be tempted to cast your way out of this hole. This code will compile

```
Result := T(class2(T).Create( i ));
```

but will likely not do what you want. This will call the static constructor of `class2` which is surely not what you want.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: `Note that earlier versions of the compiler` would you happen to know in which version this was fixed?

Comment: @Johan The cast is needed in XE7, I have a suspicion that it might have changed in Seattle, but I only know this from comments here, and my memory could easily be wrong

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if the constructor is virtual why not calling the overrride? Isn't it hidden if you don't override?

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi If I understand your question correctly, if there is an overridde it does get called (I know that from the code that this question was derived from) but I guess that is the point about it being virtual. It is known that a valid constructor (be it the base class constructor or the descendant class one) will be called.